# Providing Facebook comments on Facebook objects on a separate site

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I have a site that shows pictures grouped by activity plus some extra data. It's a mashup of Facebook data and some other data.

I would like to let users comments on the activities and photos, and then have those comments appear on Facebook as well under the activities and comments. Yet it appears that the social plugin for comments doesn't support Facebook objects - only URLs.

EDIT:To be more clear, Facebook deprecated the FBML, and tells us to use HTML and JavaScript. But there is no obvious UI for Comments for JavaScript (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)/)

Am I missing something? Do I have to write my own UI for photo and activity comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bill you will need to use the graph api and one of the sdk's, i use php sdk for the exact same function.

refer to post object https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#comments

> **Create**
>
> You can write to the POST_ID/comments connection to post a comment to
>   the post by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream
>   permission and following parameters.

refer to php-sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

i use REQUEST method to catch post by page and the api to push to the graph.  my sample below.
NOTE: this assumes you have Facebook php sdk 3.1.1 installed on your server.

---

```
$postid = $_REQUEST['postid']; // id of the post
$message = $_REQUEST['msg'];  // users message for comment
$params = array(
'access_token' => ''.$access_token.'', // user access token and read_stream perms needed
'method' => 'post',
'message' => ''.$message.'',
);
try {
$sendComment = $facebook->api('/'.$postid.'/comments', 'post', $params);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  echo 'AF error: '.$e.'';
  }
}else{

}
```

Comment: So the question is - does a prefab UI control for comments in the Graph exist? A Social Connector for Facebook objects? Or do you have to write your own UI code?

Comment: i could not even find a good enough sample to get started with, i had to hand write and debug every line.

Comment: i added a very simplified version of what i am doing, keep in mind your probally gonna need more, such as escaping characters from the message and a fallback for an id when there is not request id.

Comment: But what about the UI? I have no trouble POSTing and GETing comments, but I'd rather use a prebuilt UI. So what I am hearing is that you had to code the UI by hand too?

Comment: Yes sir, i did using 3 pages in php and ajax.  you can login my beta app and see the flow if you like https://AnotherFeed.com